# Issues using portaudio as git submodule with cmake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, linker, portaudio

I am working on a project, lets call it `AudioPlayer`, that depends on PortAudio. For pretty much all my other dependencies, I am using [conan](https://conan.io); unfortunately PortAudio doesn't have a conan package available. PortAudio uses CMake, so I decided to add the [PortAudio repository](https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio) as a submodule in the root directory.

My directory structure looks like this (leaving out other projects):

```
/
  /portaudio <-- git submodule with CMakeLists.txt

  /GlobalLib
    CMakeLists.txt
    other files

  /AudioPlayer 
    CMakeLists.txt
    other files

  CMakeLists.txt <-- Main CMakeLists.txt
```

The main `CMakeLists.txt` looks something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(AudioPlayer)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# conan.io stuff
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo_multi.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)

# include PortAudio directory
add_subdirectory(portaudio)

# add my program and other projects
add_subdirectory(AudioPlayer)
add_subdirectory(GlobalLib)
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` for my `AudioPlayer` project looks like:

```
project(AudioPlayer)

# add source files to target
add_executable(AudioPlayer main.cpp ./lib/SomeClass.cpp ./lib/SomeClass.h)

# link libraries
target_link_libraries(AudioPlayer
    PRIVATE
        GlobalLib # <-- some other lib of mine
        CONAN_PKG::spdlog
        CONAN_PKG::argparse
        CONAN_PKG::libsndfile
        portaudio # <-- portaudio dependency
    )

target_include_directories(AudioPlayer
    PUBLIC
        ../GlobalLib
    PRIVATE
        ../portaudio/include
    )
```

Now the `GlobalLib` dependency links and builds like it should, but I get this error:

```sh
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~3\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.300\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe
 /nologo @CMakeFiles\AudioPlayer.dir\objects1.rsp 
/out:AudioPlayer.exe 
/implib:AudioPlayer.lib
 /pdb:C:\Users\maris\CLionProjects\RouteExamples\cmake-build-debug\AudioPlayer\AudioPlayer.pdb 
/version:0.0 
/machine:x64 
/debug 
/INCREMENTAL 
/subsystem:console 
..\GlobalLib\GlobalLib.lib 
portaudio.lib # more after this for the conan libs, added new lines so the text would wrap around

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'portaudio.lib'
```

`GlobalLib` works, and the program links to `..\GlobalLib\GlobalLib.lib`, which is correct. What I am having a hard time figuring out is why it links to portaudio as `.\portaudio.lib` when it exists at `..\portaudio\portaudio.lib`. And ideas?

Comment: The name of the target create by portaudio project is `PortAudio` (see [CMakeLists.txt:12](https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L12)). So you need to link exactly with that **target**, not with `portaudio`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I guess CMakeTargets are case sensitive then?

Comment: Except functions and macros names, everything else In CMake is **case sensitive**: variables names, targets names, properties names, tests names, etc.